# How do you display a binary search tree?

Tags: binary-tree

I'm being asked to display a binary search tree in sorted order.  The nodes of the tree contain strings.

I'm not exactly sure what the best way is to attack this problem.  Should I be traversing the tree and displaying as I go?  Should I flatten the tree into an array and then use a sorting algorithm before I display?

I'm not looking for the actual code, just a guide where to go next.

Comment: a drew a dam and then a tree.  now i'm confused and thirsty as well.

Comment: Ok, I guess I'll give this to the first person who answered since both answers were good.  Geeze, I see my delete method here is going to be fun as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this a [binary **search** tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree) (BST)?  A "just" [binary tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree) (not **search**) has no properties that would in any way help you (indeed, there may **not** be any order defined among the payloads!), but for a BST the situation is totally different (indeed the first wikipedia page I pointed to gives concise pseudocode (well, OK, Python;-) for in-order traversal of a BST -- not for just *any* binary tree of course.

So, did you omit the absolutely-crucial word **search** between "binary" and "tree" in your question and tag?

Comment: oh, and the python "callback"...passing functions as params still hurts my head.  i'm clearly new at this.

Answer (score 4):

Check out your options for [Tree Traversal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal), it's easier than you might think.  Good luck :)

Comment: +1 Excellent link, thank you.  Clearly I was meant to use recursion here.  I'm still having trouble with that one.

Comment: @gakeit Don't have to use recursion, but it is probably the easiest way to start with. Otherwise you've got to build up a list of objects to process and whatever parameters they need (only advantage of this is that you avoid running out of stack space). Also, seeing how its homework, they almost definitely assigned to get some experience with recursion.

Answer (score 1):

Binary Search Tree is a just a tree that you can print as a classic ways (preorder, inorder, preorder)

for example :

```
print(node){
    if(node != null){
       printOut(root.value);
       print(node.left);
       print(node.right);
    }
}
```